# get nullpointer using getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(tag)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, tabactivity

I'm using TabActivity to implement tabs in my project and I want to communicate with activities of tabs and invoke some methods from tabActivity and I use method below:

```
CoachActivity activity=(CoachActivity) getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
```

but `activity` is null. `CoachActivity` is Tab1 activity.

My code is a bit long so I don't post it here. I double checked everything and I'm sure the problem isn't about the setup of my tabs. I set the current tab and I checked that `CoachActivity` is created.

Comment: `LocalActivityManager` has been deprecated for about two years. `TabActivity` has been deprecated for a similar length of time. Please consider switching to a modern implementation of tabs: `FragmentTabHost`, action bar tabs, `ViewPager` and a tab-style indicator, etc. Or, go with plain `Views` as the tabs in an activity directly holding a `TabHost` and `TabWidget`.

Comment: Tnx a lot for your your comment. I'm using API level 10 so I can not use fragments (I suppose). If it's possible help me with other ways possible. I searched about it and could't find anything not using both TabActivity and FragmentTabHost. post tutorials links. Thank you very mush @CommonsWare

Comment: "I'm using API level 10 so I can not use fragments (I suppose)" -- the Android Support package has had a backport of fragments for about two years.

Comment: @CommonsWare hey man I did what you've said to me. I implement my tabs with viewPager but I have the same problem again. I posted my code here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17792076/implementing-tabs-with-simple-views-and-fragments/ (ignore first paragraph :) ) please help me Thanks