# implementing tabs with simple views and fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

After one week struggle with common ways of implementing tabs like TabActivity and fragments and viewPager I failed to get a instance of Activities or fragments of tabs and couldn't find a way to solve the issue. So I decided to implement it in a different way. First I make a tabWidget with a simple button. In android developer website I find out a way to replace fragment in runtime. so the only thing remains is that how to get access to tab fragments to invoke methods from my FragmentActivity.

here is my FragmentActivity using pageViewer. I get nullpointer when I want to get fragment object of my tab in `setup()` method:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    OnTabChangeListener, OnPageChangeListener {
    private TabHost mTabHost;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String, MainActivity.TabInfo>();
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
private TabInfo mLastTab = null;

private class TabInfo {
    private String tag;
    private Class clss;
    private Bundle args;
    private Fragment fragment;

    TabInfo(String tag, Class clazz, Bundle args) {
        this.tag = tag;
        this.clss = clazz;
        this.args = args;
    }

}

class TabFactory implements TabContentFactory {

    private final Context mContext;

    /**
     * @param context
     */
    public TabFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    /**
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory#createTabContent(java.lang.String)
     */
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        View v = new View(mContext);
        v.setMinimumWidth(0);
        v.setMinimumHeight(0);
        return v;
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Log.d("checking", "setup tabs...");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // //
    initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); 
    }
    intialiseViewPager();
    // //
    setup();
    // ///
}

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab
                                                            // selected
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void intialiseViewPager() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments
            .add(Fragment.instantiate(this, CoachFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments
            .add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LogingFragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,
            HistoryFragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(
            super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1000000);
}

private void initialiseTabHost(Bundle args) {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);
    TabInfo tabInfo = null;
    View tabView1 = createTabView(this, coach");
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab1").setIndicator(tabView1),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab1", CoachFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    View tabView2 = createTabView(this, logbook");
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab2").setIndicator(tabView2),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab2", LogingFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    View tabView3 = createTabView(this, "history");
    MainActivity.AddTab(this, this.mTabHost, this.mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator(tabView3),
            (tabInfo = new TabInfo("Tab3", HistoryFragment.class, args)));
    this.mapTabInfo.put(tabInfo.tag, tabInfo);
    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
}

private static void AddTab(MainActivity activity, TabHost tabHost,
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, TabInfo tabInfo) {
    // Attach a Tab view factory to the spec
    tabSpec.setContent(activity.new TabFactory(activity));
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

public void setup() {
    ....
                        CoachFragment fragment=(CoachFragment) mPagerAdapter.getRegisteredFragment(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
                        fragment.setTempView(R.id.welcome);
                        fragment.animate();
                    ....
}

public void onTabChanged(String tag) {
    // TabInfo newTab = this.mapTabInfo.get(tag);
    int pos = this.mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    this.mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            .inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
}
```

}

my pageAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;
private HashMap<Integer, Fragment> registeredFragments=new HashMap<Integer, Fragment>();
/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    registeredFragments.remove(position);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}


public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
    return registeredFragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

and my LogingFragment. the other 2 fragments are exactly the same one:

```
public class LogingFragment extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }
    return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.coach_activity, container, false);
}
```

}

Every Thing works perfect and all looking and swiping works fine but in setup() method I get nullPointer. please help me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured it out what is the cause of nullpointer. pager adapter should be like this:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

Fragment screens[];
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, MainActivity context) {
    super(fm);
    screens = new Fragment[3];
    screens[0] = Fragment.instantiate(context,CoachFragment.class.getName() );
    screens[1] = Fragment.instantiate(context,LogingFragment.class.getName() );
    screens[2] = Fragment.instantiate(context,HistoryFragment.class.getName() );
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    if(index <= screens.length)
    {
        return screens[index];
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return screens.length;
}
```

}

so instantiating view pager changes like below:

```
private void intialiseViewPager() {


    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    //
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}
```

Thanks to @Bruno Mateus

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend running and testing the sample Effective Navigation which uses Tabs and ViewPager

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/index.html

Comment: Salam Mohsen. Thanks for your answer. I completely finished implementing My tabs using PageViewer. My problem is that when I want to change fragment tab layout I need fragment object of my tab but in every approach I get null instead. I'll post my entire activity and fragments. plz show me where is my problem exactly. Thank you very much bro...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are new to android, so let me point you in the right direction (if you are not new to android, my apologies):

If you want to use tabs in your app, the newest and best way to do this is to use [Action Bar tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

This only involves editing your `menu.xml` file and adding an `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method to your main activity.

Also, to answer your question,

> so the only thing remains is that how to get access to tab fragments to invoke methods from my FragmentActivity

You shouldn't use your fragments to invoke methods from your fragment activity.

Again, I will point you in the right direction with this video, ["Programming Android with fragments"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyXvq_kwfzg). It is a little long, but it will explain how to use fragments.

Use the video's example of fragments and combine it with example code from the action bar tabs page.

Best of luck

**Quick edit to clarify: You should use action bar tabs because that is the newest and easiest way of using tabs. It is the new 'best practice'. TabWidget and TabActivity are older, more complicated, and might even be deprecated for all I know.

Comment: I'm using api level 10 so I don't think I able to use ActionBar Tabs.

Comment: In that case I suggest you seriously consider using action bar sherlock.

Comment: @Mohamad Ghadourian ^^yep I forgot about that. action bar sherlock provides support of the action bar for lower api levels.

Comment: any help with the code I'v posted? I don't thing anything changed with my problem using actionbar. please tell me where I did wrong.

Comment: so did you change your code to use the actionbar and actionbar tabs? if so, please update your question with that new code so we can see what is wrong. if not, I cannot help you because I am too new to android to have any knowledge about older ways of implementing tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GrilledUI](https://github.com/Auxx/grilledui) library. It will do all the dirty work for you, even load tab list from XML.